# How do run a powershell script as an admin?

Tags: powershell

I have the silent uninstall/wait/install script below that I need to push out to users, but I need to script it so it runs as administrator and I found some scripts, but I'm not understanding how to script it, any help is appreciated. Also, do I have to put the administrator script in twice? (i.e. in the first line of the uninstall script then before the line of the 2nd install script) or just once when I run it?

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "On-Screen Takeoff"} | foreach-

object -process {$_.Uninstall()}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 25

$arguments="/quiet"

Start-Process "\\davisconstruction.com\ROOT\Installs\OnCenter\OST\Testverion3906\ost3906.msi" $arguments
```

Comment: do you want to run it on mac?

Comment: No on a windows machine, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways:

1. You can right-click on "Start" --> "Windows PowerShell Module" or "Windows PowerShell ISE" by going to "Start" --> "Administrative Tools" --> "Windows PowerShell Module" or "Windows PowerShell ISE".
   Select "Run As administrator".
   Anything you run in that window will be as "Administrator".
2. Run your script as:

   Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -verb runas -ArgumentList "-file fullpathofthescript"

Comment: Would this is be right if I did #2: Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -verb runas -ArgumentList "-file Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "On-Screen Takeoff"} | foreach-
object -process {$_.Uninstall()} 
Start-Sleep -Seconds 25
$arguments="/quiet"
Start-Process "\\davisconstruction.com\ROOT\Installs\OnCenter\OST\Testverion3906\ost3906.msi" $arguments

Comment: It seems that using" 'start-process powershell -verb runas -argument' shows an error below, but still ends up working, any ideas? Start-Process : Missing an argument for parameter 'ArgumentList'. Specify a parameter of type 'System.String[]' and try again. At C:\Users\TEMP\AppData\Local\Temp\0f078c98-bbed-48be-966d-58e2f5f40e8c.ps1:1 char:47 + start-process powershell -verb runas -argument <<<< + CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: I would create your install/uninstall script and then call that script with "-file" argument.

Comment: I tried to do the below, but I'm having issues not don't fully understand, thanks again.

$username = '.\admin'

$password = 'P@ssword1'

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "On-Screen Takeoff"} | foreach-object -process {$_.Uninstall()}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 25

$arguments="/quiet"

Start-Process "\\davisconstruction.com\ROOT\Installs\OnCenter\OST\Testverion3906\ost3906.msi" $arguments